# Why does this webkit animation look sketchy?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I shamelessly tried to rip JQTouches solution for animating a flip between two internal pages (div's). But did I miss something, a CSS rule perhaps? Cause I think it looks a bit funny..

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/wije/x3xz2/4/

Here's the original:
http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#animations

Comment: Looks fine to me. Could be your configuration, version or hardware. 18.0.997.0 (Developer Build 116462 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: looks good on Safari and Chrome OS X Lion

Comment: works identically for me, running Chrome 16.0.912.77, Win7

Comment: chrome 17, jsfiddle one is nice & smooth, jqtouch is laggy

Comment: @AlexK. Try the jqtouch one in a smaller window (roughly the size of the div in the jsfiddle)

Comment: thanks for looking. It got a lot better for me once I started up a fresh chrome window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 animations need to be separate, and then you add 2 event handlers for the animation endings; once the first div is hidden, show the other one.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean but I did take your advice on having 2 event handlers and I think it worked a bit better, so thanks.